# Error in sparseLU's colsPermutation and rowsPermutation in Eigen

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen

Here is the code I have tried. Below the code are my questions.

The code is in C++. You do NOT need to include the Rcpp-libraries, but I use them to compile the code from R.

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <Rcpp/Benchmark/Timer.h>
using namespace arma;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List sparseLUSolverFirstTime(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> xx, Eigen::VectorXd b){

  Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> solver;

    solver.compute(xx);
     //const Eigen::PermutationBase<Eigen::PermutationMatrix<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic,int>> P_C=solver.colsPermutation();
     //const Eigen::PermutationBase<Eigen::PermutationMatrix<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic,int>> P_R=solver.rowsPermutation();
     const Eigen::PermutationBase<Eigen::PermutationMatrix<-1, -1,int>> P_C=solver.colsPermutation();
     const Eigen::PermutationBase<Eigen::PermutationMatrix<-1, -1,int>> P_R=solver.rowsPermutation();

  Eigen::VectorXd x=b;
  x = solver.solve(b);
  //const double det = solver.logAbsDeterminant();
  return Rcpp::List::create( x,P_C,P_R);
}
```

I have problems extracting the column and row permutation matrices from Eigen in C++.

I have tried with the uncommented and commented line of code. I get the error:

```
'const class Eigen::PermutationBase<Eigen::PermutationMatrix<-1,-1,int>' has no member names 'eval'; did you mean 'evalTo'?
```

Can someone help?

Comment: If the issue is independent of Rcpp, please provide a [mre] without it (people wanting to help _could_ edit your code themselves, but it is you who wants help).

Comment: Without trying to actually compile your code, I assume the issue is that you try to assign something to a `Eigen::***Base` object. Just use `Eigen::PermutationMatrix<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic,int>` for `P_C` and `P_R`.

Comment: Thanks! I will later today try to add a reproducible example without the extra code. I tried with your suggestion. But now the compiler returns: 'IsRowMajor' is not a member of 'Eigen::PermutationMatrix<-1,-1,int> same goes for <Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic, int>. And it says several other member functions are not present.